# How to hide modal pop up on browser back button

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have an application where I will show `Modal Popup` on successful insert, update and delete. But after performing this when I move to next page and coming back to previous page on hitting browser back button the `Modal Popup` is getting displayed, I don't want to display this pop up on hitting back button. How can I solve this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Page.PreviousPage==null) {mpeModalPopup.Show(); }
    if (Session["Tasks"] == null)
    {
        Server.Transfer("login.aspx");
    }

    else
    {
        string strTasks = Session["Tasks"].ToString();
        if (strTasks.Contains("205"))
        {


            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                mpeModalPopUp.Hide();
                funPageLoadData();
                CheckPopup();
                Session["url"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ReturnBack();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont seem to have handled **Page.IsPostBack** boolean property on your **page_load event**.

`if (Page.PreviousPage==null) {mpeModalPopup.Show(); }`

Comment: If, upon submission of your query, the page makes a postback, then you have to handle **Page.IsPostback** boolean property. For more information [Page.IsPostBack MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

Comment: This is what I handled is it correct `if (!IsPostBack)
                   {
                       mpeModalPopUp.Hide();`  }

Comment: try using like this
`if (IsPostBack) { mpeModalPopUp.Show(); }`<br /> why do you handle for 'not postback'. the real thing is that you want to show popup only on postback, so handling the otherway round shows a bit less of the scenerio. moreover 'not postback' scenerios are more than 'postback' scenerios if you analyze your execution tree.

Comment: Even I tried that too `if (IsPostBack) { mpeModalPopUp.Show(); }` but still it is showing `pop up` on hitting browser back button

Comment: ok... you can try this too... `if (Page.PreviousPage==null) {mpeModalPopup.Show(); }`. for more information checkout [Page.PreviousPage on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx)

Comment: can you post your code here which deals with the opening/closing of modal popup...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8731/discussion-between-user-and-uday0119)

Answer (score 2):

For opening the popup (after postback) asp.net changes the html or inserts a javascript function to show the modal popup.

The only solution I know of is triggering an ajax postback (with an UpdatePanel) instead of a full postback when you click the button(s). This way the popup is loaded by an ajax call and won't display when you press the backbutton later on.

Comment: This is what I handled is it correct `if (!IsPostBack)
                   {
                       mpeModalPopUp.Hide();`}

Comment: The problem is that your code behind won't even run when the back button is clicked, the page is loaded from cache. If the last page load (postback or not) had a popup, it will show that popup again.