# Model popup extender remains open even if I click OK

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

```html
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeBusinessException" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkTemp" PopupControlID="divBusinessException" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="false"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

```csharp
protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["URL"] != null)
    {
        Response.Redirect(SafeConvert.ToString(ViewState["URL"]));
    }
    else
    {
        mpeBusinessException.Hide();
    }
}
```

Above is my ASP tag and clock button event. I have 2 issues:

1. when I click OK button popup disappears but I Navigate back to this page popup appears ( may be cache issue but didn't find solution.
2. when popup appears and without clicking the OK button I navigate to back page (though browser) and then forward to that page pop still there.

Kindly help me to find out the solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometime it happen due to Catch , i did't tried my self but what you can do is, hide `ModelPopUp` and then redirect to other page,

```
 protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["URL"] != null)
            {
                mpeBusinessException.Hide();// hide you popup
                Response.Redirect(SafeConvert.ToString(ViewState["URL"]));
            }
            else
            {
                mpeBusinessException.Hide();
            }
        }
```

maybe this do a trick.

Comment: protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["URL"] != null)
            {
                mpeBusinessException.Hide();// hide you popup
                Response.Redirect(SafeConvert.ToString(ViewState["URL"]));
            }
            else
            {
                mpeBusinessException.Hide(); 
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); // a/c to your logic I just reload page (self redirect) this solve issue no. 1
            }
        }

Comment: but browser back and forrwrad button doesnt hide the popup on navigation

Comment: I know this question will come .. as a solution we have to hide the popup just like we did in 1st scenario. whenever we navigation from this popup page to another page

Comment: This may be not proper solution.. hope it will work and look into this.. maybe it help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619595/how-to-hide-modal-pop-up-on-browser-back-button

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to ajax, Are you using Updatepanel ?

Comment: try setting the update panel property UpdateMode="Always".

Comment: please post this as comment, this is not answer to question

Answer (score 0):

**prevent browser back button just by removing previous page history**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.forward();
        function noBack() {
            window.history.forward();
        }
    </script>
```

**call above function in model popup fuction**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "Script", "noBack();", true);
```

**on button event refresh the page for issue no. 1**

```
 protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["URL"] != null)
            {

                mpeBusinessException.Hide();// hide you popup
                Response.Redirect(SafeConvert.ToString(ViewState["URL"]));
            }
            else
            {

                mpeBusinessException.Hide();
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
            }
        }
```

> just 1 lagging is is even pop OK button pressed we can't go back
>   through browser button we have to navigate through menu navigation